# Change prices with stored procedure for all products in the same category

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure that changes the prices of all articles with the same category. I can only use 2 input parameters; `@artikelcategorie` (category) and `@ingangsdatum` (Date of which the price change will start).

If you enter `'lux'` (Category) and `'10-19-2017'` (Date) for example it should change the prices of all articles with that category by a 10% increase.

I'm literally stuck on this point.

The database looks like this;

[image]

Currently I have this in as SQL code

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type ='P' AND name = 'spVerhoogPrijzen')
DROP PROCEDURE spVerhoogPrijzen
    GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spVerhoogPrijzen
(
    @artikelcategorie varchar(3),
    @ingangsdatum date
)
AS 
BEGIN 

   BEGIN TRANSACTION 

   UPDATE artikelprijs SET einddatum = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @ingangsdatum) 
   WHERE catcode = @artikelcategorie AND einddatum > @ingangsdatum; 

   IF @@ERROR <> 0 
   BEGIN 
      ROLLBACK 
      RAISERROR ('Error', 16, 1) 
      RETURN 
   END 

   --INSERT INTO artikelprijs VALUES (?, ?, @ingangsdatum, '2099-12-31')

   COMMIT 
   END 
GO
```

Comment: The first part will not work as well. `artikelprijs` hasn't column `catcode`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Is it possible to JOIN tables inside a stored procedure then?

Comment: Yes, [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
UPDATE ap SET
ap.einddatum = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @ingangsdatum), 
ap.prijs = ap.prijs*1.1  
FROM artikelprijs AP 
JOIN artikel a on a.artikelnr = ap.artikelnr
   WHERE a.catcode = @artikelcategorie AND einddatum > @ingangsdatum;
```

However you got a begindatum and an enddatum, maybe you would insert a new record instead of updating

Comment: For me Inserting a new row is indeed better. Thanks for your solution, I will check if I can fit it in.